# Why are string theorists interested in entanglement entropy?

Tags: string-theory, ads-cft, holographic-principle, entanglement-entropy

I have been reading some papers by Ryu-Takyanagi but I am not seeing a good explanation as to why entanglement entropy of the boundary CFT is a good observable to probe the possible bulk quantum gravity.

Is there any sense of non-renormalizability about this observable? 
Any kind of deformation invariance? (like Witten index)
Is it even defined for CFTs at finite temperature or at arbitrary coupling?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Which papers? What are the precise references?

Comment: @Qmechanic the standard reviews on Ryu-Takyanagi..